# Ubuntu don`t see 1 of my hard drives

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

I have a dual boot system with 3 hard drives:
- drive 1 (hitachi 500Gb SATA) has two size-equal partitions NTFS (Windows 7) and Ext4 (Ubuntu 14.04 without swap);
- drive 2 (hitachi 500Gb SATA) has one partition NTFS;
- drive 3 (Seagate 320Gb IDE) has one partition NTFS.

So the problem is I don`t see my NTFS partition on drive 2 at all in Ubuntu.
Windows have an access to all these partitions (except Ext4 of course).

This is my screenshot of blkid command:
[image: ims]

Maybe the problem is that I have 2 same hitachi hard drives?

Comment: I always turn Windows off completely.

Comment: well then, what does gparted say about the drive

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/l5nZfzp.png

Comment: okay, i see. so ubuntu *does* see the drive when you run blkid. what's the problem? is it that you can't *mount* the drive or something?

Comment: What's the output of `sudo lsblk -f`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `blkid` gets confused what is actually on the drive.
If it truly is just a filesystem without partition table (what seems to be what gparted is thinking), then you still might be able to mount it directly.
You can check for it yourself with hex dump:

```
dd if=/dev/sdc bs=16 count=1 | hexdump -C
```

If the the line contains `NTFS` like this:

```
00000000  eb 52 90 4e 54 46 53 20  20 20 20 00 02 08 00 00  |.R.NTFS    .....|
```

Then you should have no problems mounting it with: `mount -t ntfs /dev/sdc /mnt`

If you want to access files as normal desktop user, you probably need to specify `-o uid=1000` etc. options as well (refer to `man mount.ntfs`).